# git pull fails "unable to resolve reference" "unable to update local ref"

Tags: git

Using git 1.6.4.2, when I tried a `git pull` I get this error:

```
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/LT558-optimize-sql: No such file or directory
From git+ssh://remoteserver/~/misk5
 ! [new branch]      LT558-optimize-sql -> origin/LT558-optimize-sql  (unable to update local ref)
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/split-css: No such file or directory
 ! [new branch]      split-css  -> origin/split-css  (unable to update local ref)
```

I've tried `git remote prune origin`, but it didn't help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548199/git-reference-conflicts-between-branches-unable-to-update-local-branch

Comment: You can manually delete ``master`` file under below location : ``PROJECT\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master``

Answer (score 1421):

Try cleaning-up your local repository with:

```
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git remote prune origin
```

---

man git-gc(1):

```
git-gc - Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository

git gc [--aggressive] [--auto] [--quiet] [--prune=<date> | --no-prune]

       Runs a number of housekeeping tasks within the current repository, such as compressing file revisions
       (to reduce disk space and increase performance) and removing unreachable objects which may have been
       created from prior invocations of git add.

       Users are encouraged to run this task on a regular basis within each repository to maintain good disk
       space utilization and good operating performance.
```

man git-remote(1):

```
git-remote - manage set of tracked repositories

git remote prune [-n | --dry-run] <name>

           Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under <name>. These stale branches have already been
           removed from the remote repository referenced by <name>, but are still locally available in
           "remotes/<name>".
```

Comment: Why does this work? What is the problem that it fixes?

Comment: The second command worked for me. Apparently I had a broken reference to a remote branch that was just created. Not sure how it happened, but glad it was a simple fix. Thanks Vitek!

Comment: It worked for me. But after running these codes I had to run "pull" request again. Thanks for a help

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'd also love an explanation of what this does and why this worked. Thanks!

Comment: Will the ``git remote prune origin`` command run on my local working copy or on the remote repository?

Comment: @user1438038 It should not remove any branches and only update remote ref's in your local working copy.  More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106712/what-are-the-differences-between-git-remote-prune-git-prune-git-fetch-prune

Comment: @vojtech vitek how do you fix this on the server?

Comment: `git gc --prune=now` outputs errors: `error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/feature/gal-42` and then `fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/feature/GAL-42` and then `fatal: failed to run repack`. `git fetch` still doesn't work afterwards.

Comment: Weirdly on the same branch i had to run `git remote prune origin` twice before the problem was fixed.

Comment: `git remote prune origin` fixed my `error: cannot lock ref` error which I saw when I ran `git pull`. Now, `git pull` works properly again. I first saw that command [in this article here](https://linuxpip.org/git-error-cannot-lock-ref/), then I saw your answer above.

Comment: If suddenly someone didn’t like the solution and the following error appeared: `fatal: bad object refs/tags/%tag-name%, fatal: failed to run repack`, then it helped me to go to the `.git/refs/tags/` folder and delete file `%tag-name%`. It was empty. After that `git pull` worked as it should

Answer (score 823):

Happened to me as well. In my case, the bad ref was master, and I did the following:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch
```

This made git restore the ref file. After that everything worked as expected again.

Comment: I did the same thing, and it solved my problem. When I opened the file in Notepad++, it was clearly corrupted.

Comment: make sure you choose the file that is giving you problems instead of master

Comment: @bia.migueis: it's not gonna damage anythin if you accidentally remove master as well though - it'll just get updated next fetch too.

Comment: Did this. Now getting another error, "error: unable to resolve reference ORIG_HEAD: No error". Edit: Fixed the secondary error with "rm .git/ORIG_HEAD"

Comment: Thanks for this solution. In my case the file for the branch was empty. How did this happen is a mystery because yesterday I was still committing changes for that branch from the same folder. After removing it and do a fetch the problem was fixed.

Comment: Worked for me but my problem was a tag so as @bia.migueis mentioned, I needed to delete the file under `.git/refs/tags/`

Comment: Any idea _why_ this happens? I'm just pushing, pulling, fetching, rebasing, merging as normal and then I come across this error. Is it an issue found in certain versions of Git?

Comment: @crmpicco AFAIR mine was corrupted due to a computer crash

Comment: @MichelKrämer Interesting. As in did you have a WSOD in Windows or something similar? When this happened the first time to me I believed it was because I didn't shut down my Virtual Machine properly, however it still seems to happen even though now I do.

Comment: @crmpicco I don't think it was a BSOD (didn't happen to me for quite some time). Must have been a power outage or something. Can't really remember. The problem has never occurred again by the way.

Comment: After doing:
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master, git fetch will remove the ref error.. but when i do the git pull again the same error comes.. so i did a git gc --prune=now.. and it worked...

Comment: Had the exact same issue; the file was filled with NULL characters :-/

Comment: If it is a submodule, it might be slightly tricky to find the ref. First check if `.git` is a folder by doing `ls -la` if not, see the contents of the file `.git` file to find the actual .git folder in which the refs are. `.git` file contents in my case:  `gitdir: ../.git/modules/my-submodule-name`

Comment: I had this problem with a few branches, and I had them all pushed, so I just deleted whole "origin" folder

Comment: Twice now in the past year I've come back to have to fix this and again, this is the only fix that actually works.

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me until I did that (prune did nothing). I run `rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/MY_BROKEN_BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: The solution provided by Vojtech Vitek didn't work for me but this solution worked.

Answer (score 186):

This did the job for me:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: git gc docs are [here](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-gc/1.6.5#git-gc---pruneltdategt)

Comment: Worked for me too. Didn't need to run `git remote prune origin`

Comment: Had to move the bad references that the terminal was mentioning out of the .git folder before that command would run, but after that this command ran, and I was able to continue merrily on my coding journey!

Comment: Running this command accused the problem in my case: ```fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
fatal: failed to run repack``` so I ran `rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` and later `git gc --prune=now` and now the repo is clean as new.

Answer (score 114):

For me, it worked to remove the files that are throwing errors from the folder `.git/refs/remotes/origin/`.

Comment: that did it! But just out of curiosity do you know why this error came? (everything was working fine and then suddenly one day this error popped). And also do you know how deleting the file solved it?

Comment: Good to hear this also fixed it for you. To be honest i have no idea what caused the error to appear. My thought was that one of the files in the folder had gone out of sync. Since none of the other fixes i found worked for me i used this as a last resort.

Comment: Worked great! Notice you have to delete all files that causing the problem (based on the error report you are getting), as if you only delete one and try pulling it will come back.

Comment: One of the possible causes may be the system crash as I described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467268/971141). Many Git GUI applications periodically run Git on your repo (to refresh the status) and if your system crashes during Git is manipulating with the references, they may end up rewritten with `NULL`s.

Comment: My system crashed just as a sync operation was about to complete and this helped.

Comment: I forced shutdown my laptop without closing all apps. It caused the issue. Deleting the C:\git\repo1\.git\logs\refs\remotes\origin helped

Answer (score 103):

I just would like to add one of the possible causes of a broken Git reference.

### Possible root cause

On my system (Windows 7 64-bit), when a **[BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) happens**, some of the stored reference files (most likely currently opened/being written into when the BSOD happened) are overwritten with `NULL` characters (ASCII 0).

As others mentioned, to fix it, it's enough to just delete those invalid reference files and re-fetch or re-pull the repository.

### Example

**Error message:**

> cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/some/branch': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/some/branch': reference broken

**Solution:**

Delete the reference `refs/remotes/origin/some/branch` which is stored in the file `%repo_root%/.git/refs/remotes/origin/some/branch`.

Comment: Same scenario on Windows 10 64bit - working in a git repo when BSOD happens. `error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/master': reference broken`. Trying to `git pull` after deleting the first file returned `fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'HEAD': cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/master': reference broken`. After deleting the second file `git pull origin master` was successful.

Comment: Simplest solution so far

Comment: Had a BSOD. This solved my problem.

Comment: this is what worked for me after all

Answer (score 101):

**Explanation**: It appears your remote repo (in GitHub / BitBucket) branches were removed ,though your local references were not updated and pointing to non existent references.

In order to solve this issue:

```
git fetch --prune
git fetch --all
git pull
```

For extra reading - Reference from [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) :

> ***git-fetch*** - Download objects and refs from another repository
>
> **--all**
> Fetch all remotes.
>
> **--prune**   After fetching, remove any remote tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.

Comment: this is simpler and looks safest than the top anser.

Answer (score 90):

Go to under flutter folder and then,

Try it:

```
git gc --prune=now

git remote prune origin

git pull
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Exactly the point. It's not enough to right the code and that's it. I hope there's an explanation

Comment: git gc --prune=now updates local repository while deleting unnecessary files. It works for me fine.

Comment: It works, thank for saving my 2 hours

Answer (score 53):

Execute the following commands:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master

git fetch

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

> Just in case, if you need to know what is
>   `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master`, you would read the **Remotes** section
>   in [Git References](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References).

Answer (score 51):

`git fetch --prune` fixed this error for me:

```
[marc.zych@marc-desktop] - [~/code/driving] - [Wed May 10, 02:58:25]
[I]> git fetch
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/user/janek/integration/20170505': 'refs/remotes/origin/user/janek/integration' exists; cannot create 'refs/remotes/origin/user/janek/integration/20170505'
From github.com:zooxco/driving
 ! [new branch]            user/janek/integration/20170505 -> origin/user/janek/integration/20170505  (unable to update local ref)
From github.com:zooxco/driving
[marc.zych@marc-desktop] - [~/code/driving] - [Wed May 10, 02:58:30]
[I]> git fetch --prune
 - [deleted]               (none)     -> origin/user/janek/integration
```

This assumes that the offending branch was deleted on the remote, though.

You can also add this to `~/.gitconfig` to automatically prune when running `git fetch`:

```
[fetch]
    prune = true
```

Comment: Your example seems incomplete: it doesn't show the `--prune` that I can see. Also proTip: remove useless password prompts after pasting examples.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I left off the output from the fetch command but I just put it into the example. Thanks for the tip on removing the password prompt too!

Answer (score 49):

In my case, the problem was solved after I've deleted all the remove reference files under the directory `.git`.

If you look at the message, it would tell you which files you need to delete (specifically).

The files to delete sit under `.git/refs/remotes`.

I've just deleted all the files there, and ran gc prune

```
git gc --prune=now
```

After that, everything works just fine.

Comment: In my case I just delete .git/refs/remotes and then update and push over server and it worked.

Comment: Thanks Uri. In my case I just deleted files under refs/remotes/origin/feature and I simply did - git pull

Answer (score 46):

I had this same issue and solved it by going to the file it was erroring on:

```
\repo\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master
```

This file was full of nulls, I replaced it with the latest ref from github.

Comment: Had the same issue, but the file `.git/refs/remotes/origin/master` was just empty. Solved the problem by removing it.

Answer (score 28):

If this error “unable to update local ref” is reoccurring, even after applying either the answer by **[Vojtech Vitek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348934/792015)** or **[Michel Krämer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15458951/792015)** you may you may have a bad ref on your local AND master repository.

In this case you should apply both fix's without pulling or pushing in between ...

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch
git gc --prune=now
git remote prune origin
```

A permanent resolution for me was only achieved after applying both fix's before push/pull.

Comment: Thanks for this. note that I replaced 'master' with the branch which was failing eg - rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/develop

Answer (score 18):

For me, I solved it this way:

```
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch
```

After that I get this message from github.

**There is no tracking information for the current branch**

So next I did to fix this was:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
git pull
```

Answer (score 15):

To Answer this in very short, this issue comes when your local has some information about the remote and someone changes something which makes remote and your changes unsync.

I was getting this issue because someone has deleted remote branch and again created with the same name.

For dealing with such issues, do a pull or fetch from remote.

```
git remote prune origin
```

or if you are using any GUI, do a fetch from remote.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Error: cannot lock ref" simply means information in /refs are corrupted and Git cannot continue to create index.lock file.

Quick fix : Remove and re-add remote.

1- Copy the SSH git URL of your existing remote. You can print it to the terminal using this command:

`git remote -v`

2- Remove the remote from your local git repo:

`git remote rm origin`

3- Add the remote back to your local repo:

`git remote add origin git@server-address.org:your-username/repo-name.git`

4- Prune remote origin
Users across online forums have reported that the command below worked for them:

`git remote prune origin`

5- Clean up and optimize local repository
`git gc --prune=now`

You can find  more info on this article:
https://linuxpip.org/git-error-cannot-lock-ref/

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Did a "git fetch" afterwards, then when I tried the "git pull", it failed due to no tracking info. Had to first execute "git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master master", the finally redo the "git pull".

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
git pull origin Branch_Name
```

`Branch_Name`, the branch which you are currently on.

If you do only a `git pull`, it pulls all other created branch name as well.

So is the reason you are getting this:

```
! [new branch]      split-css  -> origin/split-css  (unable to update local ref)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master

$ git fetch
```

From `bitbucket.org:xx/mkyong-tutorials`

```
df0eee8..3f7af90  master     -> origin/master

$ git pull
```

Already up to date.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to work with

```
git remote update --prune
```

Answer (score 4):

delete file for particular branch manually from your project

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin/master
 git gc --prune=now
 git pull
```

Comment: git prune work for me. thanks for a straightforward answer

Answer (score 3):

Tried these but didn't work for me:

```
$ git gc --prune=now
$ git remote prune origin
$ git fetch --prune
```

I had to get this fixed by deleting the local folder and cloning again.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had a local branch named `feature/phase2` and the remote branch was named `feature/phase2/data-model`. The naming conflict was the cause of the problem, so I deleted my local branch (you could rename it if it had anything you needed to keep)

Comment: Same issue here - ours also was a Mac/PC case-naming issue, which made it tricky to spot (one name was capitalized, the other not - and it worked on the PC, but not Mac)

Answer (score 2):

If `git gc --prune=now` dosen't help you. (bad luck like me)

What I did is remove the project in local, and re clone the whole project again.

Comment: This is a "I got an error message so I bought a new computer"-approach which I didn't expect to get any upvotes on this website.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Tower and for some reason my folder name was `.git/refs/remotes/origin/Github`. Changing it to lowercase `.git/refs/remotes/origin/github` solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

#### When it is caused by Google Drive `desktop.ini` files

Google Drive client for Windows creates `desktop.ini` files in each folder. If your git repository is in a directory that is being synced with Google Drive, then the `desktop.ini` files will cause the git repository to fail with something like:

```bash
cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/desktop.ini': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/desktop.ini': reference broken
```

To solve this error you might want to delete the `desktop.ini` files in your git repository.

If you have [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about-wsl) setup, then you can use the following command to delete the `desktop.ini` files:

> **Note: ⚠️ This command will delete all `desktop.ini` files in all `.git` directories in your `<project_directory>`.**

```bash
find <project_directory> -type d -name .git -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} find {} -type f -name desktop.ini -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm -vf {}
```

If you just want to delete the `desktop.ini` files in a specific `.git` directory, then you can use the following command:

```bash
find <.git_directory> -type f -name desktop.ini -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rm -vf {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything else however none worked for me apart from this solution. Just delete git's remotes folder from your project directory. In my case it was.

```
.git/refs/remotes/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. i follow following steps

1)switch your branch which having issue  to other branch

2) delete that branch

3) checkout again.

Note:- You can stash you uncommitted changes and put it back again.

Answer (score 1):

Got this issue when trying to clone from a `git bundle` created file, none of the other answers worked because I couldn't clone the repo (so `git gc` and removing/editing files was out of the question).

There was however another way to fix this - the source file of a `.bundle` file was begining with:

```
# v2 git bundle
9a3184e2f983ba13cc7f40a820df8dd8cf20b54d HEAD
9a3184e2f983ba13cc7f40a820df8dd8cf20b54d refs/heads/master
9a3184e2f983ba13cc7f40a820df8dd8cf20b54d refs/heads/master

PACK.......p..x...Kj.0...: (and so on...)
```

Simply removing the fourth line with vim fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 # remove the reference file of the branch "lost"
 rm -fv ./.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/v1.6.9-api-token-bot-reader
 
 # git clear everything 
 clear ; git reset HEAD --hard ; git clean -xdf ; 

 # subdue the current branch and pull all changes from the remote
 clear ; git fetch --all -p ; git pull --all --rebase ; clear ; git branch -a

 # git will "know" how-to handle the issue from now on
 #     From github.com:futurice/senzoit-www-server
 # * [new branch]      feature/v1.6.9-api-token-bot-reader ->
 # origin/feature/v1.6.9-api-token-bot-reader

 # and push your local changes
 git push
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `git prune origin` and that did the work.

Answer (score 1):

Writing down a specific case that might cause this problem.

One day I pushed a branch named "feature/subfeature", while having "feature" branch on remote.

That operation worked fine without any error on my side, but when my co-workers fetched and/or pulled any branch, they all had the exact same error message `unable to update local ref`, `cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/subfeature`.

This was solved by deleting `feature` branch on remote(`git push --delete origin feature`) and then running `git remote prune origin` on my co-workers' repo, which generated messages including `* [pruned] origin/feature`.

So, my guess is `git fetch` was trying to create `subfeature` ref in `feature` folder on git internally(.git/...), but creating folder failed because there was `feature` ref already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `git branch --unset-upstream`

I was facing the problem earlier but I just solved it when I saw this command on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

for me the git-gc and prune solutions didn't work.
I also couldn't delete the ref file of the problematic branch since it didn't exist locally when I inspected the ref folder.

since I didn't have any important information locally that wasn't on remote, I've just deleted the local repo and cloned it again.
that made the pull redundant since after git clone the repo is already up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with composer update. But for me it only worked after I cleared the composer cache and after deleting the content of the vendor folder:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
git gc --prune=now
git pull
composer clear-cache
composer update my/package
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while using SourceTree.  I tried to pull again and it worked.  I think I Was witching branches (checkout) too fast :).

My situation is a bit different from the poster's because my repository has been relatively cooperative, without any apparent corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same msg but with a directory, got a failed msg on pull.

git --prone did not help me either.
Turns out there was a file with the same name as a directory created remotely.

Had to go to .git\logs\refs\remotes\origin and erase the locale file - then pull again, all good.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the problem today.

Troubleshooting method:
With SourceTree on Windows Servers, you may try to run it as an Administrator. That fixes my problem of "unable to update local ref" on Atlassian Source Tree 2.1.2.5 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 in domain.

If you can too replicate this situation, it proves that the problem is caused by permission issue. It's better to drill down and find the root cause - probably some particular files are owned by other users and such - otherwise there's an unwelcome side-effect: you'll have to run SourceTree as Administrator for the rest of eternity.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't recommend this. You will end up with even more files with incorrect permissions. And you will need to run everything that manipulates with repository files as an administrator. Isn't it better to simply fix the permissions in the first place?

Comment: You're right. But only after making it work as an Admin had I figured out it was the permission issue. So this was a step in my diagnosing procedure, not a perfect solution per se.

Comment: Sure. But many users may just take your answer as a solution without really knowing the consequences. Maybe better if you add the fixing of the permissions as a suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue when repository was deleted and created with the same name. It worked only when I **re-set the remote url** like below;

> git remote set-url origin [GIT_REPO_URL]

Verify the remote url:

```
git remote -v
```

Now, all commands should work as usual.

Answer (score 0):

We got this issue when a developer on Mac created a branch with a greater than ">" symbol in the branch name.

That caused problems in TeamCity, and on local Windows based computers running SourceTree. BitBucket let it through without any problems.

To resolve the user removed the branch and recreated it. Which was nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this useful, I was getting this issue chronically, although not constantly, and it was because I had git directory within Dropbox, removed it from Dropbox and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if two branches have the same name on case-insensitive file systems, for example `main` and `Main`. One solution is to delete one of them.