# Git error on git pull (unable to update local ref)

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I only have a master branch and I'm getting this error every time I try to `git pull`:

```
error: Couldn't set refs/remotes/origin/master
From /var/lib/git/xxx/project
 ! a0f80ea..49177a3  master     -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
```

And when I run `git pull origin master` I get:

```
error: Couldn't set ORIG_HEAD
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'ORIG_HEAD'.
```

I have been searching but can't find why.

Comment: Where is the local repository? Did you create it as a different user than the one you are using to execute the pull? It sounds like a file permission problem.

Comment: Yeah you are right after you said the owner of the project files was another user, now my question seems so fool, but you gave me the answer, please make it an answer to choose it as the best ;)

Comment: please @tpg2114 add this as an answer to chose it

Answer (score 665):

My team and I ran into this error, *unable to update local ref*, when doing a pull in SourceTree.

> **Update 2020:** Per @Edward Yang's answer below, @bryan's comment on this answer, and [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998832/git-pull-fails-unable-to-resolve-reference-unable-to-update-local-ref) you may need to run both `git gc --prune=now` and `git remote prune origin`. Running only the former has always worked for me but based on ppl's responses I think both are necessary to address different causes of the error.

We used:

```
git gc --prune=now
```

This removes any duplicate reference objects which should fix the issue.

*Here are a few links where you can learn more about git references and pruning* :

[git tip of the week](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/11/git-tip-of-week-gc-and-pruning-this.html)

[git-prune documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune)

[git references](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References)

Comment: May need both these commands:`git gc --prune=now`
`git remote prune origin` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998832/git-pull-fails-unable-to-resolve-reference-unable-to-update-local-ref

Comment: worth noting that "git remote prune origin"  the "origin" is whatever your git is complaining about --- "refs/remotes/origin/master" <--- whatever origin is in that string.

Answer (score 337):

I solved as below:

`git remote prune origin`

Comment: Would be good if you added a comment about what it does. Is this always safe to run?

Answer (score 71):

with gitbach line commande, use `git update-ref` to update reference of your local branch:

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/[locked branch name]
```

then pull using `$ git pull`

`[locked branch name]` is the name of the branch that the error is happening because of mismatch of commit Ids.

Comment: This fixed my issue... Just a NOTE: The [Locked branch name] mentioned above is case sensitive. Read the message and ensure you use the exact path and name

Comment: Lovely, Works!!

Comment: Note that I also needed to delete the branch that was causing the problem

Answer (score 36):

### Problem

**Windows users** can often have this problem

```
git pull
```

gives the error: `error: cannot lock ref` `unable to update local ref`

### Cause

**Cause a)** There are multiple branches, whose
**names from the beginning up to any slash (or to the end), differ only in upper and lower case**.

```
Branch name clashing (upper/lower case)
#######################################

# Example 1)
#############################
feature/releasecandidate/fix123
feature/releaseCandidate/improveFeature789
------------------------
               ^
  Identical from beginning up to a slash (here the 2nd one)
  except for the marked letter, where the upper/lower case differs




# Example 2)
#############################
releaseBranch
releasebranch
-------------
       ^
  Identical from beginning to the end
  except for the marked letter
```

**Cause b)** Also a problem on linux: **One branch is a prefix of another, with a slash boundary**:

```
Prefix with slash-boundary
#######################################

# Example 1) - also a problem on linux
#############################
feature/release2021
feature/release2021/fixIssue07
                   ^
              slash boundary

# Example 2)
#############################
feature/release2022
feature/Release2022/fixIssue99
        ^          ^
  differing case   slash boundary
 (problem on 
   windows)
```

### Solution

Remove the cause (see exact **Cause** above).

```sh
# inspect your branches, to see if you have the upper/lower case problem
git ls-remote --heads YOUR-GIT-URL
```

For example: create a branch-naming policy, e.g. all in lower-case letters; or letters before the last slash in lower-case. Or some smart hook, that detect a violation. (but note: In cause a) the problem is only on windows, not on linux).

### Background

The problem is that windows stores these branches (from example 1 and 2) in the `.git` folder

```sh
# inspect the files/folders under
.git/refs/remotes/origin/
```

and in **Cause a)** windows cannot distinguish
the differences in upper/lower case, so git on window goes crazy.

In **Cause b)** you cannot have a folder (e.g. `feature/release2021/`) with the same name as a file (`feature/release2021`).

### Workaround

A short-term workaround that often works (until you've removed the cause) is:

```sh
git pack-refs --all

# delete the contents of .git/refs/remotes/origin/*  
rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/*

git pull; git pull; git pull   # all good? yes!
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the clue that finally solved it for me. The repository I was working on is several years old and two years ago someone made a branch called 'test'. Last week another person made a branch called 'Test/[new branch]'. Windows could not create a directory named 'Test' because the branch 'test' already exists.

I renamed the 'test' branch to Test/[something useful] and the problem was solved.

Comment: thank you ,it is happening only in windows for me

Comment: Doing some "rm -rf" command for an error mostly occuring on Windows, feels somewhat...

Comment: Excellent comment, this was my actual problem. People naming branches in a way that git on windows hated. I removed those branches (they were test branches) and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 26):

Try to use this command in your git repository root folder:

```
rm .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Where is this folder on Windows?

Comment: I found it. It's whatever directory you cloned to

Answer (score 21):

`rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master`

It works to me!

Comment: if you're on a branch, change `/master` into `/branch_name`

Answer (score 21):

This was enough for Windows:

> git pack-refs --all

Comment: Based on the docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs situations with too many refs can arise:

"This command is used to solve the storage and performance problem by storing the refs in a single file, $GIT_DIR/packed-refs. When a ref is missing from the traditional $GIT_DIR/refs directory hierarchy, it is looked up in this file and used if found.

Subsequent updates to branches always create new files under $GIT_DIR/refs directory hierarchy.

A recommended practice to deal with a repository with too many refs is to pack its refs with --all once, and occasionally run git pack-refs."

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

## DIRECT ANSWER

```
git remote prune origin
rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
git fetch
git pull origin master
```

Run the above command step by step

Answer (score 17):

I discoverd the same Error message trying to pull from a Bitbuck Repo into my lokal copy. There is also only one Branche Master and the command `git pull origin master` lead to this Error Message

```
From https://bitbucket.org/xxx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Couldn't set ORIG_HEAD
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'ORIG_HEAD'.
```

Solution as follows

1. `git reflog` find the number of the last commit
2. `git reset --hard <numnber>` reset to the last commit
3. `git pull origin master` pull again without error

Answer (score 13):

This works perfectly for me:

```
rm -rf .git/packed-refs .git/rr-cache
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a little tough but very certain solution for me.

Comment: This worked, but I'm fairly certain it blew away my local branches which weren't associated with a remote. Proceed carefully.

Answer (score 10):

Ensure the user that is executing the `git pull` is the same user that created the repository. The file permissions are incorrect.

Comment: For me I had to change the owner of the files in the repo I was trying to git pull in to the correct user with chown. I think this is basically what you were saying although it wasn't obvious to me when I read this.

Comment: I agree with this, check that owner and group are set to user willing to pull in ".git" repo ( happens if you pulled a branch being  "root") a "sudo chown -R " did the job in my case.

Answer (score 10):

What happened over here?
The local references to your remote branches were changed and hence when you run `git pull`, git doesn't find any corresponding remote branches and hence it fails.

```
git remote prune origin
```

actually cleans this local references and then run `git pull` again.

Suggestion - Please run with `--dry-run` option for safety

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

Now it keeps on running prune automatically.

Answer (score 5):

I've remove the local ref of the branch with:

```
git branch -d -r REPO/.git/refs/remotes/origin/BRANCHNAME
```

then I can do my fetch.

Or more radically

```
rm -rf REPO/.git/refs/remotes/origin
```

This works everytime too.

Comment: This works, i have tried all other stuffs, prune them etc... and go back to the simple step :(

Comment: I've eventually realized that this (`git branch -d`, didn't need the -r) was the fix for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Clone the repository again, and copy the .git folder in your broken project.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a very niche situation, but: I run Windows in a Parallels VM on my MacBook Pro, with my local repos stored on the VM's disk, which is shared with macOS.

If I have a file open in a Mac app from a repo that's located on the Windows VM, I sometimes get the "unable to update local ref" error. The solution when this happens is to simply close the file or quit the Mac app.

Comment: This is exactly what my situation was. I had the files open in vs-code and trying to commit using visual studio in the Parallels VM. Closing VSCode and then doing a git pull worked perfectly. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Remove file .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/[Locked Branch Name]

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. To covince me otherwise please add an explanation of how this should work and why it is supposed to help with the problem. Highlighting the differences to seemingly similar existing other answer would be a bonus. Especially the upvoted one by Babak.

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried all other answers, but this is the one that helped in the end.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me on OSX where I use a case insensitive file system. Somehow another developer pushed a branch with the same name but different case: `My-Branch` vs `my-branch`.

I already had `My-Branch` checked out and got the error "unable to update local ref" when I did a pull probably because the file system thinks `My-Branch` == `my-branch`.

Since we use Github I could solve the problem by deleting one of the branches via Github's GUI.

Comment: In my case, both the conflicting branches belonged to another user so I couldn't delete one. Instead, I deleted the branch ref file under .git\refs\remotes, and that fixed it (temporarily - the issue will come back each time I pull until the other user deletes one of his branches).

Comment: My issue was also due to local branch and remote having different capitalization. Deleting local branch, using the prune command above, and then checking out from origin solved it

Answer (score 2):

`git pull origin <branch_name_you_are_currently_at>` will pull just that branch.
It may or may not give you merge conflicts. Resolve them and commit them.
It worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This error with (unable to update local ref) can also happen if you have changed passwords recently and there's some fancy stuff integrating your Windows and Linux logins.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a PC user - Reboot.

Honestly, it worked for me. I've solved two strange git issues I thought were corruptions this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I was updating from within Eclipse and I got many errors.
So I tried updating from a DOS command window, and got the same issue.

Then I tried the solution " git gc --prune=now "
This gave messages that the files were locked in the refs directory.

Eclipse must have had a locked on something in the "refs" directory.
The solution I found was to simply close Eclipse.
Then I updated the repository from DOS with a " git PULL " command, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by deleting the locked branch file. It may seem crude, and I have no idea why it worked, but it fixed my issue (i.e. the same error you are getting)

Deleted:
`.git/refs/remotes/origin/[locked branch name]`

Then I simply ran

```
git fetch
```

and the git file restored itself, fully repaired

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple step:

```
git gc
git pull --prune origin branchname
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my debian server as the disk is full. No temp file could be created as no space left on device. After cleaning some files, it worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
rm .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps - or even works at all. To covince me otherwise please add an explanation of how this should work and why it is supposed to help with the problem. Highlighting the differences to seemingly similar existing other answer would be a bonus. Especially the upvoted one by Babak.

Answer (score 0):

One command solution [for Linux/bash users]

1. Changing permission by changing ownership of the file.

`sudo chown username -R .git`

*(replace 'username' with your username)*

Use sudo if owner of the file is sudo.

2. Deleting the file will also solve the problem.

`sudo rm .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master`

Answer (score 0):

Open Git Bash as admin cd to folder,
Git add .
Git commit -m "your message"
Git push
he will now either use built in credentials or ask for username/pw,
If built in credentials or username/pw don't work create a PAT and close the window where they ask for credentials a screen will pop up that asks for a PAT

Answer (score 0):

This one will probably solve your problem, you get a broken e.g.:

```
unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/develop': reference broken
```

you have to remove the broken reference and the use the git fetch

```
git fetch
```

and now you can simple use git pull

```
git pull
```

reference link:
https://codeahoy.com/q/2/Git-pull-fails-Unable-to-resolve-reference-refs-remotes-origin-master-reference-broken

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is an issue with windows with the folder naming convention

the branch name is

```
BE | WEB | description
```

The error says:

> (unable to update local ref)

Windows is trying to create a folder like BE-|-WEB-|-description

This is not allowed as the folder cannot be created with those charachters  \ / : * ? " < > |

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue but solved it with another way. In my case I reinstalled windows and the whole dev drive belonged to my former account. I had to give full rights to my new and current account for my git folder.