# On git pull, "unable to resolve reference" and "Undefined error: 0"

Tags: git

My morning started with `git pull`, just like any other morning:

```
$ git pull
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/card-declined: Undefined error: 0
From github.com:instaedu/instaedu
 ! [new branch]      card-declined -> origin/card-declined  (unable to update local ref)
```

(FYI, "card-declined" is a branch I pushed to GitHub just last night, and hasn't had any activity since then.)

I've never seen that error before, so I looked it up and found this question: [git pull fails “unalble to resolve reference” “unable to update local ref”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998832/52263). The top-voted answer there says to try running `git gc --prune=now`, so I did that:

```
$ git gc --prune=now
error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/card-declined
error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/card-declined
fatal: loose object b28488de1ef3f6887eef99c0316a654d1803e6af (stored in .git/objects/b2/8488de1ef3f6887eef99c0316a654d1803e6af) is corrupt
error: failed to run repack
```

It didn't seem to fix anything, though now I see that something seems to have been corrupted since yesterday.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: perhaps a fresh `git clone`? it looks like your repo is corrupt...

Comment: @nneonneo That may be what I end up doing, but I'm still curious to see if it can be fixed first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git pull fails "unable to resolve reference" "unable to update local ref"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998832/git-pull-fails-unable-to-resolve-reference-unable-to-update-local-ref)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I re-cloned the repository so I could continue working, I did keep the old corrupted one around, in case I happened to find a way to fix it. Unfortunately, I found no such fix.

If you run into this problem, your best bet is just to `git clone` the repository again. Hopefully you've already pushed your latest changes to a remote before the repo got corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by deleting the bad refs, e.g.:

```
del .git\refs\remotes\origin\card-declined
del .git\refs\remotes\origin\card-declined
```

It was mostly a hunch, but it seems to have worked because I did not care about the troublesome refs.