# Git push errors for new staging rails application after heroku forking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, staging

I am trying to set up a staging copy of my production app for testing on heroku. i used

```
$ heroku fork -a myapp-production myapp-staging
```

and the stagin app works fine- now i try to add it as a remote to my git with:

```
$ git remote add staging git@heroku.com:myapp-staging.git
```

and seems to be added to my git remotes without a problem. But when i try to push changes to it with:

```
$ git push staging master
```

i get the following errors:

```
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remote/staging/master: No error
error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/staging/master'.
Everything-up-to-date
```

Not sure what the problem is....

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998832/git-pull-fails-unalble-to-resolve-reference-unable-to-update-local-ref

Comment: Thanks Cortex - i feel like such a neuron. I tried   $ rm .git/refs/remotes/staging/master  and that now lets me push to staging but when i run the staging app i lose all the css- wierd - i wonder whats going on??

Comment: Review your server log and browser console.