# Git reference conflicts between branches (unable to update local branch)

Tags: git, github

I'm experiencing the following error while trying to **git fetch** a remote branch:

> error: Ref refs/origin/remotes/my-branch is at **some-hash** but expected **another-hash**
>   From github.com:**my-repository**
>   ! **some-hash** my-branch -> origin/my-branch (unable to update local ref)

I have no idea what the hell just blew up. Any enlightenment?

Comment: Did somebody (perhaps yourself) force-push a modified history to the remote repository from somewhere else?

Comment: Along the same line, you can view `git log --pretty=oneline origin/my-branch` to see the history inside your own repository and then look in the history in github to see the history there. If they don't match, it means that the history has been changed by you or somebody else by force. That's bad and people who change history are bad.

Comment: Somebody screwed up. Do git related problems happen a lot where you work? If so, then ask: Do we need the benefits of git? If yes, ask: Are we willing to put in the time to get everyone trained in it? If no to this, or the previous, then your enlightenment will come naturally.

Comment: i've found who screwd it up

Comment: I was seeing this error in SourceTree, so immediately ran to StackOverflow. After reading the answers (no doubt all correct) above, I went back to SourceTree and just pressed "Pull" again. Everything worked.

Git gremlins. They were slow this morning.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### I've found this error's cause:

Someone has created another branch with the same name, but different case.

### What happened?

Git for windows isn't case sensitive. So, things just got crazy! Git couldn't distinguish one from another, mistaking the hash of each's head.

### Solution:

Just cut the evil by its root. Wrong remote branch was deleted and evererything is nice as ever.

Comment: this, my team leader just kill us with a Develop and develop branch. !!

Answer (score 26):

For other googlers who get here: [this is also another less drastic approach](http://thenitai.com/2013/05/28/git-unable-to-resolve-reference-and-unable-to-update-local-ref-messages/):

Navigate to `.git\refs\remotes\origin` directory - delete the master file,

Then do another `git pull` and it synchronizes successfully.

Comment: I know this is a couple years late, but I just wanted  to add that i had multiple refs in a bad state. Mine happened to be in two locations: .git/refs/remotes/origin and .git/refs/tags (tags was also bad). I removed the bad refs and fetched again with success. I guess you can just nuke all the refs, and refetch, but I just nuked the ones that the error specified.

Comment: This solves the issue, the ref file has all zeros and not the actual hash of the branch.

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me.

Comment: Wish I could upvote a second time. This has helped me out twice.

Comment: This worked. thanks for the solution. PS: delete all the files inside the `.git\refs\remotes\origin` folder and do a `git fetch`

Answer (score 2):

In my case it wasn't the branch name per se. I had a situation like this:
this branch name `dev/a_random_branch_name` was conflicting with `Dev/completely_different_branch_name`. I was so confused that both the branches were not even close that I didn't notice at first that the folder name was mismatched.

To fix it I did the following:

1. remove all contents of .git\refs\remotes\origin\dev
2. create a new branch that matched the folder name casing already in source control: `Dev/a_random_branch_name`

Answer (score 0):

You also get that error message with "[`git fetch <group>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d26e26a3f50670c52b95149f4b52ec1396512053/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup>, when "`<group>`" of remotes lists the same remote twice, unnecessarily failed when parallel fetching was enabled.

That has been corrected with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

See [commit 06a668c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06a668cb90a6e8628f295adb6177855bb0a85a4a) (19 Jan 2023) by [Calvin Wan (`CalvinWan0101`)](https://github.com/CalvinWan0101).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d26e26a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d26e26a3f50670c52b95149f4b52ec1396512053), 27 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06a668cb90a6e8628f295adb6177855bb0a85a4a): fix duplicate remote parallel fetch bug
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Calvin Wan</sup>

> Fetching in parallel from a remote group with a duplicated remote results in the following:
>
> ```
> error: cannot lock ref '<ref>': is at <oid> but expected <oid>
> ```
>
> This doesn't happen in serial since fetching from the same remote that has already been fetched from is a noop.
>
> Therefore, remove any duplicated remotes after remote groups are parsed.