# How to tell Git to ignore errors with remote development branches when pulling master

Tags: git

**TL;DR**
How can I tell Git to completely ignore remote branches that I don't care about?

**Details**

I am working in a very large project hosted in an internal Git repository. On one of my local clones, my master branch is tracking the remote master on origin. For this particular clone, I don't care about anything besides master. However, when I issue `git pull`, I sometimes see:

```
error: cannot lock ref 
'refs/remotes/origin/<branch>': is at <hash> but expected <other hash>
```

Where `<branch>` is some random person's development branch that I don't care about, and my master branch ends up not getting completely updated. I have successfully used `git gc --prune=now` and `git remote prune origin` as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7348934/2615940), but it has happened multiple times now, and I don't want to keep fixing it manually. I can also use `git pull origin master:master`, but I'd prefer to just use `git pull`.

I don't care about this branch and never will. I've never checked out anything besides master in this clone, and am not tracking anything else:

```
m:\<path>\> git branch
* master
```

How can I tell git to stop doing whatever tracking information it's doing in the background when I just want to pull master?

**Additional Note**
Our team's move to Git is very recent, and we're still working out kinks in our workflow. I don't know if the other developer is doing something weird or not, but I don't really care - I want to know how I can tell Git, "No matter what happens to the other branches, just pull the one I ask when I say `pull`."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell git to only fetch master branch instead of all branches:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```