# GitHub Desktop Error: fatal: git show-ref: bad ref refs/tags/desktop.ini

Tags: windows, git, github, github-desktop

Github continuously throws this error. They seem to stack the error boxes so that if I leave it running on that repository, dozens of these error pop-ups will accumulate. Poor Design
[image: git error popup]

When I push commits I get this other  collection of errors:
[image: more git errors]

Errors in the error pop-up:

- "error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/desktop.ini': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/desktop.ini': reference broken
- error: could not remove reference refs/remotes/origin/desktop.ini From https://github.com/-----/archives_archiver
- [deleted]    (none)   -> origin/desktop.ini
  fatal: bad object refs/desktop.ini
  error: https://github.com/-----/archives_archiver.git did not send all necessary objects

Thus far I have tried 'git fetch' and 'git remote prune origin'
No such luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+desktop.ini

Comment: Remove all files `desktop.ini` under `.git/`directory.

Comment: See in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72076111/1256452) in the duplicate.